# Witchwood Zero Mana classification

Tags: hearthstone

There are cards that look at your entire deck and active an effect depending on if they are even or odd.

Are zero mana card like backstab and wisp consider even or odd?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

0 is even, so it counts as an even cost card.